# Multiples of a number using Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I have wrote the following function for finding the multiples of an input number.
When I try to give negative numbers the output is only positive list.How can I modify my code to allow negative numbers to be listed in the output?

My Try :

```
multiples n = if n<0 then result1 else result2
where
   result1 = [x | x <- [0..], x `mod` (-n) == 0]        
   result2 = [x | x <- [0..], x `mod` n == 0]

  Input : take 5 $ multiples (-3)
  Output: [0,3,6,9,12]
  Expected Output: [0,-3,-6,-9,-12]
```

Comment: multiples n = [0,n..]

Comment: Thanks a lot No_signal :) Thats even compact

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can avoid branching if you just multiply the argument by successive natural numbers:

```
multiples n = map (* n) [0..]
```

This works for all `n`, positive or negative. (And zero, if you don't mind an infinite list of 0s.)

Comment: Thats a classic just one line of code :) . Thank you so much

Comment: Make sure you saw @no_signal's comment; that's an even shorter approach.

Answer (score 2):

You need to negate `x` in the negative version:

```
result1 = [-x | x <- [0..], x `mod`(- n) == 0]
```

Of course this only solves your immediate problem @chepner's answer is much more elegant

Comment: Thanks a lot epsilonhalbe